# What can I write in R to denote "any value"?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe "data" containing 10 variables A to J (which all contain 0s and 1s) and 500 rows:

I need to make a second set of 10 variables AY to JY based on the variables A to J such that:

- for AY, if A==1 then AY takes the value 1 with 80% probability and if A==0 then AY takes the value 1 with 20% probability
- for BY, if B==1 then BY takes the value 1 with 80% probability and if B==0 then BY takes the value 1 with 20% probability
  And so on...

Right now, I have the variables A to J stored the dataframe "data", and have the following as my code:

```
out <- paste0(LETTERS[1:10], "Y")
data2 <- data.frame(data)
colnames(data2) <- out
for (i in out) {
  data2[i] <- ifelse(**???**, rbinom(length(out), 1, 0.8), rbinom(length(out), 1, 0.2))
}
```

What would I write instead of the question marks to denote "if any value in the list of variables AY:JY is equal to 1, execute the first argument, otherwise execute the second argument"?

Comment: Please add the code to generate your `data`.

Comment: you could do this in one line without loops: `data <- data.frame(matrix(0:1, 500, 10, dimnames = list(NULL, LETTERS[1:10]))); data[sprintf('%sY', names(data))] <- rbinom(500 * 10, 1, c(0.2, 0.8)[unlist(data) + 1])` then check that the 1s in the original are ~80% 1s in the after: `mean(unlist(data[c(FALSE, TRUE), -(1:10)]))` and same for the original 0s: `mean(unlist(data[c(TRUE, FALSE), -(1:10)]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below one solution that should work.

1. Starting data

```r
set.seed(4854)

df <- data.frame("A" = sample(c(0,1), 500, replace = TRUE),
                 "B" = sample(c(0,1), 500, replace = TRUE),
                 "C" = sample(c(0,1), 500, replace = TRUE),
                 "D" = sample(c(0,1), 500, replace = TRUE),
                 "E" = sample(c(0,1), 500, replace = TRUE),
                 "F" = sample(c(0,1), 500, replace = TRUE),
                 "G" = sample(c(0,1), 500, replace = TRUE),
                 "H" = sample(c(0,1), 500, replace = TRUE),
                 "I" = sample(c(0,1), 500, replace = TRUE),
                 "J" = sample(c(0,1), 500, replace = TRUE)
                 )
```

2. Saving original data

```r
df2 <- df
```

3. Apply with `apply` a function which randomly samples with replacement
   (i.e. `replace = TRUE`) 1 or 0 with the probabilities which you indicated
   according to whether the original data is 0 or 1

```r
df2 <- apply(df2, c(1,2), function (x)
  ifelse(
    x == 1,
    sample(c(0, 1), 1, prob = c(0.2, 0.8), replace = TRUE),
    sample(c(0, 1), 1, prob = c(0.8, 0.2), replace = TRUE)
  ))
```

4. Renaming of columns

```r
colnames(df2) <- paste0(colnames(df),"Y")
```

5. Output

```r
head(df2)
#>      AY BY CY DY EY FY GY HY IY JY
#> [1,]  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1
#> [2,]  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
#> [3,]  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0
#> [4,]  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0
#> [5,]  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
#> [6,]  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that doesn't seem to work unfortunately. I get a column that just has exclusively 1's that way for some reason. Is there just something I can write in my provided code to replace the question marks?

Comment: Hi @Samantha, sorry I was indeed wrong. I modified the code above: more precisely I specified c(1,2) for the margin argument of the apply function so that the function applies to each cell of the data.frame. So, it should work now! If something was still wrong, don't hesitate to ask me again. Otherwise, please mark the answer as accepted to make it easier for other users to find the right answers. (NB: I also added an excerpt of the output; so if you set the same seed value as I indicated at the beginning of the code (part 1"Starting data"), you should have exactly the same result than mine)

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to Stack overflow - thanks for the tip on marking answers as accepted. :)

Comment: Hi @Samantha, Thank you for validating the answer and glad I could help you. I wish you all the best.